# Navigation property from another DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Imagine having 2 DbContexts:

```
DbContextA {
    DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

DbContextB {
    DbSet<Group> Groups{ get; set; }
}
```

In such case, is it possible in entity `Person` to have navigation property to `Group` like this:

```
class Person {
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

I have a request to divide one DbContext to multiple DbContexts with separate entites, but before going into it, I want to know if navigation properties will work between contexts so I dont need to change queries because I use navigation properties in queries like `persons.Where( p => p.Group.Name == "GroupName")`.

Comment: You can't add relations between contexts. A context represents a standalone model whose job is to server a specific business scenario. Why use *two* contexts? What are you trying to achieve with this? Why "divide" the context? Was there one huge context perhaps that tried to serve multiple scenarios until it became unwieldy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It's not possible. EF adheres pretty closely to DDD (domain-driven design). The context is your unit of work, but it's called a "context", because it's the class that implements the concept of "bounded contexts" from DDD. In other words, you should have one context per subdomain of your application, and the context should fully encapsulate that subdomain. Crossing over between two contexts would indicate that you haven't sub-divided your domain correctly.

If the two entities really are part of the same subdomain, then they should exist in the same context. If not, then it would be incorrect for one to reference the other, anyways.

Comment: Is this still the "way to go" in 2020 and with EF core 3.0?